# Does choosing *Host* for zabbix action field apply to all items / triggers?

Tags: zabbix

If I choose the Host Condition under Actions, does it apply to all triggers on the Host?

It isnt clear from the documentation as it says

> Specify hosts or hosts to exclude.
>
> = - event belongs to this host.
>
> <> - event does not belong to this host.

or do I need to apply the action to all triggers on a host individually?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action will match all events from triggers that include at least one item from that host. There is no need to reference individual triggers.